# Wait before starting JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to play a sound every time a user gets a new notification. The way I am loading the notifications on my page is simple:

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        var $container = $("#noti");
        $container.load("notify.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('notify.php');
        }, 1000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This works by updating a div container with whatever number the PHP code sends out. it retries every second (probably not the most efficient way, but it works).

I have another piece of code that checks when the div content changes, then creates an alert box (which I will change to playing a sound when the script is done):

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('noti');
if(window.addEventListener) {
   // Normal browsers
   myElement.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', contentChanged, false);
} else
   if(window.attachEvent) {
      // IE
      myElement.attachEvent('DOMSubtreeModified', contentChanged);
   }

function contentChanged() {
   // this function will run each time the content of the DIV changes
         alert("js is working");

}
```

This script works, however it also creates an alert or the first loading of the notifications. This is because it starts of as an empty div, then it loads the data, which sets off this alert script. The only way I could think about going round this is delaying the script from loading for a couple of seconds whilst the AJAX script does its business.

Does anyone know a way I could delay this second script from doing anything for the first few seconds after page load, or perhaps a better way about going round this?

Comment: Before attaching the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, could you not just check if `myElement` is empty or not?

Comment: Why are you using both jquery and vanilla js event handling?

Comment: Honestly, the plain JavaScript I took from another site. It works, that's all that matters I guess :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing that, use a custom event which you trigger when load finishes:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(reloadContainer, 1000)
function reloadContainer() {
    $container.load('notify.php', function success() {
        $container.trigger('loaded')
    })
}
$(myElement).on('loaded', contentChanged)
```

Comment: The thing is, that doesn't check to see if the content changes or not :/

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified will fire after every .load(), regardless of whether you think they're the same or not(.load() replaces the DOM)

Comment: Oooh, I see. I just tried this however, and the entire system just stopped working :3

Comment: Wait, no I implemented it wrong. Still, sadly doesn't do what it says on the tin. This isn't important, just a nice feature I'd llike to add to my site. Is there really not just a simple way of delaying a script?

Comment: Sure there is - just put your code in a setTimeout.

Comment: Already tried that though and it didn't seem to do... anything O.o

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not very good with plain old JS. How would I use `setTimeout` in the second piece of JavaScript?